# Catch unexpected input on single character read in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, test, error-handling

I have a bash script, which, at one point asks the user for confirmation. I do this by reading a single character, which is then transformed to lower case and checked if it is 'y'. If not, the script exits.

Now, if I simply press enter on the input read, I get `error: unary operator expected`. How can I prevent this issue or catch the error?

Code snippet:

```
echo -ne "Confirm [y/n]: "
read -n1 uc

if [ ${uc,,} != "y" ]
then
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408) and [Using single or double bracket in bash](/q/32210/23408).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement should work properly:

```
if [ "${uc,,}" != "y" ]
```

Explanation: When `uc` is empty your test is expanded by the shell as follows:

```
if [  != "y" ]
```

while with the quotes it is

```
if [ "" != "y" ]
```

Rule of thumb: **Always** use quotes around shell variables that contain strings when expanding them; they may contain spaces or be empty, which when unquoted often confuses the command they're passed to (too many or missing parameters).

Comment: Thumbs up on the "Rule of thumb" of always putting double-quotes around variables in tests!